# {$gte} statement in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, where-clause

my document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579f205f20754ea8cc58e22e"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-08-01T10:11:00.000Z"),
    "httpRequestData" : {"charset" : "null", "encoding" : "gzip, deflate"},
    "status" : "normalized"
}
```

and I want to query it like: select some columns and apply a "where" clause specifying a "status and a date range".

So:

```
db.fingerprint.find({"status" : {"$ne" : "deprecated"}},
                    { "date": 1, 'httpRequestData.ipAdress': 1},
                    {"date" : { $gte : new ISODate("2016-08-30") }})
```

But it doesn't seem to select the time range I want, showing records from dates before the one I stated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the date range query incorrectly; you should put it in the same document/object as your status query i.e.

```
db.fingerprint.find(
    { 
        "status": { "$ne": "deprecated" }, 
        "date": { "$gte": new ISODate("2016-08-30") }
    },
    { "date": 1, "httpRequestData.ipAdress": 1 },
)
```